# Reading information from a text document

Tags: python, import

I just started writing a code that should create, compare and load entries of a text file. 
The program is asking you for your name, your age and your height. It will then create a text file like such:

> Vincent,18,190

I have gotten this to work but I can not figure out how to load this information back into Python once I have closed it. I want to call `load` and then it will load all the text file entries and display them as:

> Name:"name"
>     Age:"age"
>     Height:"height"

Ho can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can open your previously saved text file like this

```
with open('myData.txt') as infp:
   for line in infp:
      # process line
      line = line.rstrip()
```

(this will also close the file for you)

If, for instance, there are three items stored per line in your file you can write

```
      name, age, height = line.split(',')
```

to get values into your variables (assuming the data is separated by commas without spaces when initially stored). Then generate the output you in the format you specified:

```
      print 'Name:"%s"' %name
      print 'Age:"%s"' %age
      print 'Height:"%s"' %height
```

as pointed out by @pepr depending on how the data was stored (spaces between the words and the commas) there might be leading/trailing blanks in the data produced by `split(',')` in which case it would be necessary to use `strip()` to get rid of any extra blanks. In the data sample shown, this is not the case and the code above should work.

Here is all of it wrapped into a function to do this:

```
def load(datafile):

   with open(datafile) as infp:
      for line in infp:
         line = line.rstrip()
         name, age, height = line.split(',')
         print 'Name:"%s"' %name
         print 'Age:"%s"' %age
         print 'Height:"%s"' %height
```

If your data is saved in a file named 'myData.txt', call the above `load` function like this

```
load('myData.txt')
```

Comment: It is comma separated.  You must split by comma and lstrip() the spaces.

Comment: @pepr Thanks for catching that .. overlooked this. Will fix it.

Comment: name, age, height = line.split(',') for this line it is expecting an intended block.

Comment: @user1365542 I don't see it .. are you getting an error when you paste this into your editor? Can you check for blanks/tabs at your end? I didn't find any here.

Comment: yes it was displaying this error when i pasted it. and there is no blanks :/

Comment: and it doesn't recognize "load"

Comment: @user1365542 `load` is a function I defined with the `def` statement. If you copy the complete solution (not the step by step) into a .py file and use your own filename it should work. I tried it here and had no problem.

Comment: it seems to work, what do i put in (Datafile) ? the myfile.txt

Comment: print ('name:"%s"') %name
NameError: name 'ename' is not defined

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Answer (score 2):

```
data = open('file.txt').read().splitlines()
for line in data:
    person = line.split(',')
    print 'Name:', person[0]
    print 'Age:', person[1]
    print 'Height:', person[2]
```

Comment: I am still a bit lost sorry, how am i going to put it, as saving and displaying are going to be two separate options?

      `def displayinfo():
          person = line.split(',')
          print ('Name:'), person[0]
          print ('Age:'), person[1]
          print ('Height:'), person[2]

      def loadinfo():
          data = open('packages.txt').read().splitlines()`

am i doing i right or not?

Comment: @Scorpil: The `open().read().splitlines()` is not correct because you are not closing the open file.  This is a kind of dirty move.  You rely on closing the file by runtime when the script ends.

Comment: @pepr yeah, agree. It's better to use 'with' statement for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
fil=open('file.txt','r')

for line in fil:                  # iterate through the file.txt line by line

  name,age,height=line.rstrip().split(',')     #now after this name='Vincent' and age='18' , height='190'

  print(name,age,height)
```

**output :**

```
vincent 18 190
```

Comment: Python doesnt like the for line in fil part. NameError: name 'fil' is not defined

Comment: @user1365542 It works fine for me. Look like you didn't copied the first line of this program?

Comment: You should also add the `fil.close()` to the end of the code.  The `f` identifier for a short living file object is better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the standard csv module to read the file lines into the rows like `['Vincent', '18', '190']`.

If you want the numbers as integers (i.e. not as strings), the strings must be converted explicitly via `int(str_variable)`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have saved the file, use this to read it:

```
import csv

filename = 'myfile.txt'

# the code that creates
# the file goes here

the_file = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'))
for line in the_file:
   # line[0] is Name
   # line[1] is Age
   # line[2] is Height
```

Comment: but the thing is that there is e Values on the same line and i somehow need to split them

Comment: The `line` should be called `row` as it is a list of items that were already split by the csv module.  The problem here is the *anonymous* `open()` as it is not possible to close it explicitly.  `the_file` is better to be called a `reader` (to cause less confusion).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
f = open('temp.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
     a,b,c = line.split(',')
     print "Name:%s\nAge:%s\nHeight:%s\n" % (a,b,c)
f.close()
```

Output

```
Name:Vincent
Age:18
Size:190
```